# How to Get Open Graph Insights for an App using Graph API or FQL

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-opengraph

I want to get the Insights for Open Graph like number of actions published, impressions, referrals etc which are shown in Admin Panel.

Is there any way to get this data using Graph API or FQL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yeah,

As long as you have the read_insights   extended permissions you can use open graph api retrieve.

some links you might find useful

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/insights/
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/insights/